# What is the Mac terminal command to remove ACL?

Tags: mac, terminal, acl

I'm trying to find the terminal command on a Mac to remove ACL to fix user permissions on a folder that gives an error code when I try to copy it (error code -41).

Answer (score 61):

Using `chmod -a` allows one to remove access control entries individually (as @geekosaur suggested).

But if you are looking to remove *all* ACLs from a file or folder, the solution is to use the brute-force option: `chmod -N` which removes all access control entries for a file or folder.

`chmod -RN` will do the same recursively for a folder and its entire contents.

Comment: You know, the funny thing here is that in the man page indicates `chmod -a# 1 file1` to remove attributes based on their numeric assignment as shown via `ls -le` -- this doesn't seem to work. Anyone have some specific examples of this working?

Comment: @ylluminate I've used it that way. Are you quoting/escaping the `#` character (to keep it from being treated as a comment delimiter), as in `chmod -a\# 1 filename` or `chmod '-a#` 1 filename`?

Comment: Good call @gordon-davisson, this particular workstation of ZSH was supposed to not require escaping of `#` on this particular workstation, but it did and that solved it.

Answer (score 4):

It's all bundled into the `chmod` command; take a look at the `-a`/`+a`/`=a` options in the [manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html).